# Unable to load nested data in MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Unable to load nested data in MVC4 with relationship once i remove relation between tables it executes .when i add tables to my model which has relationship with Employee table it loads nothing

I'm using 2 tables Employee and Requests.Added with ADO entity Data Model 
This is My DataController

```
using Bareed.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Bareed.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Data/

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult EmployeeRequests()
        {
            List<EmployeeRequests> CO = new List<EmployeeRequests>();
            using ( EmployeeContext dc= new EmployeeContext())
            {
                //var cust = dc.Customers.OrderBy(a => a.ContactName).ToList();
                var cust = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.EmpName).ToList();
                foreach (var i in cust)
                {
                    var requests = dc.Requests.Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(i.EmployeeID)).OrderBy(a => a.RequestDate).ToList();
                    CO.Add(new EmployeeRequests
                    {
                        Employee = i,
                        Requests = requests
                    });
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = CO, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

    }
}
```

This is my DataView.cshtml

```
    <h2>DataView - Nested Tabuler Data using AngularJS</h2>
<div ng-controller="DataViewController">
    <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Employee ID</th>
               <th>Employee Name</th>
               <th>Iqama No</th>
               <th>Company</th>
               <th>Department</th>
               <th>Nationality</th>               
           </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="O in Requests">
            <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">

                <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.EmployeeID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.EmpName}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.IqamaNo}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.CompanyID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.DepartmentID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.NationalityID}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sub">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request ID</th>
                            <th>Employee ID</th>
                            <th>Iqama Number</th>
                            <th>Request Type</th>
                            <th>Request Date</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Agent Name</th>
                            <th>Agent Contact</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="a in O.Requests" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">

                            <td>{{a.RequestID}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.EmployeeID}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.IqamaNo}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.RequestType}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.RequestDate.slice(6,-2) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>                           
                            <td>{{a.EmailAddress}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.AgentName}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.AgentContact}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my Employee.cs class which was Auto Generated by Data Model . and also i want to Display Company Name , Department Name , Nationality instead of their ID . in my DataView .

```
    namespace Bareed.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string IqamaNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NationalityID { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: seeing as you are fetching all of them with no filter why do you bother requesting Employees first and then looping them... just fetch the requests and loop into your new object or better return them directly. As for the rest it is not clear... only give the broken version not both its hard to work out what is there and what isn't. Ie why isnt there a virtual list to Requests from employee

Comment: Dear Seabizkit I want to display All Employees Data thats why i am fetching all of them , after fetching the employees i am doing a conditional statement so that if request table matches with employee table it shouldd fetch the data and display in nested view. when i debug the code it shows data in my CO object but doesnt display in Gridview.